# How can I make a chart like this in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, charts, bootstrap-4

How can I create this chart with animations?

[image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width:40%">
    Free Space
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" style="width:10%">
    Warning
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" style="width:20%">
    Danger
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not working by the way.

Comment: include bootstrap stylesheet to ur html page or refer to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/ esp on multiple bar section